# Changing a variable in a function has no effect

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
unsigned char xor4(unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 8){
        if((getBit(c1, i) ^ getBit(c2, i)))
             setBit(c1,i);
        else clearBit(c1, i);
        i+=2;
    }

    return c1;
}
```

The above code is supposed to be a very simple function to set every other bit in a character based on the result of an xor with every other bit in a second character. For some reason, this simply doesn't work. The program seems to just ignore my while loop and return the original function.

Oh and here are my getBit, setBit and clearBit functions.

```
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n){
  return (c & 1<<n) >> n;
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n){
  c = c & (~(1<<n));
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n){
  `c = c | (1<<n);
}
```

Comment: `return c1 ^ c2;` would be a more efficient way to do the same.

Comment: an important question: what exactly made you think that the *while loop* is not working? how could you have verified that the loops is actually working?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath's point may be a little too subtle. The OP has wrongly assumed that the while loop isn't executing. Some judicious printfs would verify that it is executing but that the setbit and clearbit calls aren't changing c1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your setbit and clearbit functions, but whatever they do, that can't change c1 in the calling function. You need to either pass the address of c1 or return the new value of c1. Or you can just use C bitwise operators. And your entire operation is just equivalent to `c1 ^= c2` (assuming that a char has 8 bits).

Edit: Given your edit, just assign the return values of your functions to c1 ... and fixe your setbit and clear bit functions ... they don't return values, and if you were using proper warning settings in your compiler it would tell you that. I've made some stylistic changes:

```
/* your getbit works but is needlessly complex */
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n){
    return (c >> n) & 1; 

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n){
    return c & ~(1 << n);
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n){
    return c | (1 << n);
} 

unsigned char xor4(unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){
    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2 )
        c1 = ( getBit(c1, i) ^ getBit(c2, i)
               ? setBit(c1, i);
               : clearBit(c1, i) );

    return c1;
}
```

Here's a faster solution:

```
unsigned char xor4(unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){
    return (c1 & 0xAA) | ((c1 ^ c2) & 0x55);
}
```

Even faster:

```
unsigned char xor4(unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){
    return (c2 & 0x55) ^ c1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the set and clear bit functions. I also edited the code because there was a typo in there. the reason I can't use c1 ^= c2 is that I have to change every other bit not every bit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I've been using a Java minded approach to C programming

Comment: @OladunniAbiodun See my edits. This should all work in Java as well (with minor syntactic adjustments), and your code will fail for the same reasons ... functions that produce values must return those values, and the caller must assign them somewhere to use them.

Comment: Thanks. the Java thinking was in the sense that I assume I'm working with objects that I'm directly accessing and forgetting that i'm working with copies of the original variable. Oh but yes I see how I just went full retard in not storing the return values of my setBit and clearBit in an actual variable. And looking even closer, my original set and clear don't actually have return statements which probably makes everything even worse. I like your last 2 solutions a lot but I heel like that isn't what is being asked of me so I think I'll go with the first one. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: @OladunniAbiodun C and Java share the property that all parameters are passed by value. (Well, the last time I used Java, which was long ago.) And yes, I fixed your setbit/clearbit in an edit.

Answer (score 3):

When you're calling `setBit` and `clearBit`, you are passing *copies* of `c1` to these functions. Thus the value of `c1` in `xor4` is not changed at all.

Replace

```
 if((getBit(c1,i)^getBit(c2,i))) setBit(c1,i);
 else clearBit(c1,i);
```

with direct set or clear operations,

```
 if((getBit(c1,i)^getBit(c2,i))) c1 |= (1 << i);
 else c1 &= ~(1 << i);
```

(but, [as was pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755689/c-while-loop-not-working-in-function/12755706#comment17234955_12755689), just replacing the function with a simple `c1 ^ c2` would be more efficient.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't use direct set and clear operations because it's an assignment and we are supposed to write the set and clear operations ourselves as part of the assignment. I've adeed those functions as well for reference